# How can I create one copy of a piece of data per subclass?

Tags: scala

I have the following trait:

```
trait Mappable {
  def toMap = {
    val mappableFields = this.getClass.getDeclaredFields.filter(...)
    ...
  }
}
```

`mappableFields` lists `this.declaredFields` and then applies static filters to the list; as such it is invariant for each class that implements `Mappable`, and ideally I'd like to be able to put it in the subclasses' singleton objects or something along those lines.  My current solution is

```
object Mappable {
  import scala.collection.mutable.Map
  private val fieldMap = Map[Class[_], Array[Field]]()
  def getFieldMap(clazz: Class[_]) = {
    fieldMap.get(clazz) match {
      case Some(array) => array
      case _ => {
        val mapFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields.filter(...)
        fieldMap.put(clazz, mapFields)
        mapFields
      }}}}

trait Mappable {
  def toMap = {
    val mappableFields = Mappable.getFieldMap(this.getClass)
    ...
  }
}
```

but I'm wondering if there's a better solution e.g. one that doesn't require a call to Map#get.  I can't turn the trait into a class.

Comment: Implementing all the logic in the trait and then creating objects implementing this trait should work. In each case getClass would mean specific subclass/object... I hope I understand correctly what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
trait Mappable {
  def companion: MappableCompanion
  def toMap = {
    val mappableFields = companion.mappableFields
    ...
  }
}

trait MappableCompanion {
    def thisClass: Class[_]
    val mappableFields = thisClass.getDeclaredFields.filter(...)
}
```

Subtypes of `Mappable` would then also define a companion object:

```
class Foo extends Mappable {
    def companion = Foo
}

object Foo extends { val thisClass = classOf[Foo] } with MappableCompanion
```

If you don't like the early initializer you can make `MappableCompanion` a class.